# Dispalying a list in combobox using visual studio(2008, express) for c sharp

Tags: ado.net

I've got a class with a list(4 item) of data and I want to show all in a combo box. how do i do that maintaining Model-View-Controller?

Comment: do you want to show the text "ALL" along with the existing values you get from a data source

Answer (score 1):

I am a simple ComboBox and my job is to display things in a list, but not so much as to have the entire thing drop off the bottom of the screen causing the user to physically tilt his monitor to select items.  Because of this, I implement a scroll-bar.  Anyhoo, I'm empty right now and I need some data, can you help out?

Regards,

ComboBox (_idCounty)

**Dear ComboBox,**

**Thankyou for your recent enquiry.  As it turns out I DO have some data for you that you can display.  Here it is.**

**Regards,**

**Model**

**PS: Make sure you listen to Controller!!!**

*In short, simply query the model for the data you require*

Comment: +1 for humor but I think there's an extra bit that we might be missing, although I might be mistaken, because it might be "I'm empty right now and I need some data, can you help out? Also I want to add something extra to the data for display purposes, will you do that for me too?"